# replicate click functionality of legend stacked bar chart

Tags: highcharts

1. following is the code:

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
   <script>
   $(function () {
       $('#container').highcharts({
           chart: {
               type: 'bar'
           },
           title: {
               text: 'Stacked bar chart'
           },
           xAxis: {
               categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
           },
           yAxis: {
               min: 0,
               title: {
                   text: 'Total fruit consumption'
               }
           },
           legend: {
               reversed: true
           },
           plotOptions: {
               series: {
                   stacking: 'normal'
               }
           },
           series: [{
               name: 'John',
               data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
           }, {
               name: 'Jane',
               data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
           }, {
               name: 'Joe',
               data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
           }]
       });
   });
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

jsfiddle linke is:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-stacked/

2. when you click on the joe the data corresponding to joe invisible and when you click on joe again the data is visible.

i want to do that by clicking a some button or i want to hide multiple objects at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `<button id="btn">Hide series</button>`

Then a click listener to the button which, depending on the state of the Highcharts graph, toggles the visibility of the data series on or off.

```
var $btn = $('#btn');
var myChart = $('#container').highcharts(); // get higcharts object

$btn.on('click', function() {
    if(myChart.series[0].visible && myChart.series[1].visible) {
        myChart.series[0].hide();
        myChart.series[1].hide();
        $btn.html('Show series');
    } else {
        myChart.series[0].show();
        myChart.series[1].show();
        $btn.html('Hide series');
    }
});
```

See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/byrz56pk/ for a working example.